# How to find users who have bought specific products and then bought other specific products

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to see how many users first bought some product from the first list and then made some purchase from the second list in 2021 and 2022.

the first list has product_id:
10000001
10000002
10000003
10000004
10000005
and second list has product_id:
20000001
20000002
20000003
20000004

I have a table with transactions and I have written a query, but it doesn't return appropriate results.
The condition is first to purchase from the first list and then from the second list (it does not have to be another purchase). How many such users and transactions are there ?
Can anyone help me ?

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS YEAR,
       count(distinct customer_id) AS Customers,
       count(distinct Transaction_id) AS Transactions
FROM dbo.transactions 
WHERE product_id IN (10000001,
                        10000002,
                        10000003,
                        10000004,
                        10000005,
                        20000005,
                        20000002,
                        20000003,
                        20000004),
        AND date >= '2021-01-01'
        AND date = (SELECT min(date)
                          FROM dbo.transactions
                          WHERE product_id IN (
                                               10000001,
                                               10000002,
                                               10000003,
                                               10000004,
                                                10000005))

GROUP BY YEAR(date)

Table:

Transaction_id   |Customer_id | Date        |product_id
1045411          | 1554411    |2022-01-05   |10000032770333
57486997         | 1554411    |2021-04-30   |20000005
66893928         | 1554411    |2021-04-28   |10000043477221
76300859         | 1554411    |2021-04-26   |10000001
10452342         | 1445444    |2022-01-06   |10000069125012
19859273         | 1445444    |2022-01-07   |10000004
29266204         | 1445444    |2022-01-08   |20000004
38673135         | 1118543    |2021-05-04   |10000043477001
48080066         | 1009576    |2021-05-02   |10000043285004
85707790         | 573708     |2022-05-04   |10000043285004
95114721         | 464741     |2022-07-08   |10000043480001
38633135         | 355774     |2022-09-11   |10000043285004
11228583         | 246807     |2022-11-15   |10000043480001
expected output:
    Date    |   SUM_Customer_id
     2021   |   1
     2022   |   1
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your input table and the expected output

Comment: Please provide us with sample data and expected result, provide it as text and NOT in an image

Comment: There is a typo in your query, instead of `20000004,
        AND date >= '2021-01-01'`  it should be `20000004)
        AND date >= '2021-01-01'`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ;WITH CTE_CustomerList(customer_id) AS
>     (
>     SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
>     FROM dbo.transactions 
>     WHERE product_id IN (10000001,
>                         10000002,
>                         10000003,
>                         10000004,
>                         10000005)
>             AND [date] BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
>     INTERSECT
>     SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
>     FROM dbo.transactions 
>     WHERE product_id IN (   20000005,
>                             20000002,
>                             20000003,
>                             20000004)
>             AND [date] BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
>     )
>
> SELECT YEAR(tr.[date]) AS YEAR,
>        count(distinct tr.customer_id) AS Customers,
>        count(distinct tr.Transaction_id) AS Transactions  
> FROM dbo.transactions tr
>     JOIN CTE_CustomerList cl
>         ON cl.customer_id = tr.customer_id
> WHERE product_id IN (
>                         10000001,
>                         10000002,
>                         10000003,
>                         10000004,
>                         10000005,
>                         20000005,
>                         20000002,
>                         20000003,
>                         20000004
>                     )
>         AND [date] BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
> GROUP BY YEAR(tr.[date])
> ```

Comment: You should add some explanation to your code